# How can I copy array data to an object that has an array and also a field?

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
var test;
var abc = [1,2,3];
test.active = [];
test.active.$selected = 123;
```

Is it possible to copy the array that contains `[1,2,3]` into the test.active array without making the test.active.$selected = 123 disappear?

When I try test.active = abc then the value $selected is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) coupled with [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to copy the elements to the `test.active` array, while keeping any properties intact.

Note: you didn't define `test` as an object, so I've changed that.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WpbEQ/)

```
var test = {}; // define as object
var abc = [1,2,3];
test.active = [];
test.active.$selected = 123;

// copy abc's elements to test.active, while keeping any of test.active's properties
test.active.push.apply(test.active, abc);

console.log(test.active.$selected); // 123
console.log(test.active[0]); // 1
console.log(test.active[1]); // 2
console.log(test.active[2]); // 3
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, yes, it's possible. But I'm not sure if you need it. In a simple way:

```
var test;
test.active = [1,2,3];
test.active.$selected = 123;
```

In that case you'll assign to `test.active` a new array. And as soon as everything is JavaScript is an object - you can add a new property to it. But from the common sense point of view - it's not a good practice to mix up 2 different data types (array and object). So in your case I would recommend to use separate properties for array and integer value:

```
var test;
test.active = [1,2,3];
test.$selected = 123;
```

**Note:** if you have a more complex array of, e.g. objects, etc - it's better to use any library for deep clone of it. But it depends on your exact problem.